# References for analytic machanics on differentiable manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

Do you know some good references which deal with vector bundles, symplectic geometry, differential geometry and computation in coordinates which apply this mathematical structures to analytic mechanics? I know Godbillon's Geometrie differentielle and mechanique analytique but unfortunately it's written in French. Thank you

Comment: A nice book, though it is not very rigorous, is Analytical Mechanics, by Fasano&Marmi. The original version, "Meccanica Analitica" (in italian) is also good.

Comment: They said The Book for this stuff is Foundations of Mechanics by R. Abraham and J. Marsden